# How to create 2 magento stores with same data except the store URL? - Magento2

Tags: magento2, store-view, installation

Actually I need 2 magento instances of same site. One is something like production site other is like dev site. I make all the changes in the dev site and show to client or some other.

I have set up main site.(http://example.com/magento) copied all the content and placced it in a new directory(http://example.com/magento2) also created a new database and imported the data from main site.

Changed database name `env.php` and changed store urls in `core_config` tbl in new database.

Now if I go to http://example.com/magento2, its working fine. But When I click the links or products it redirects to main site urls like http://example.com/magento/men.html instead of http://example.com/magento2/men.html

Even the admin login is redirected to main site url.

Any other changes are needed other than changing store url in db and db name in `env.php`?

Answer (score 0):

That should be it other than clearing your cache and redeploying static content just to be sure you haven't bought over the old configurations cache.

Run:

```
bin/magento cache:flush
```